# JavaScript: Make a key-value data structure from 2-dimensional array(header, rows)

Tags: javascript, arrays, key-value

I am completely new to JavaScript, and taking a beginner level course at school.

I have an assignment in which we are asked to create a function that converts a 2D array into a dictionary, by using column headers as a key and data as a value for each row.

I think I know how to separate the first row (to use as headers) and the rest of the rows (to use as rows), but I am having a trouble converting this into a dictionary.

Here is what I have written so far:

```
function rowsToObjects(data) {
    var headers = data[1];
    data.shift();
    //var rows = alert(data);
    var rows = alert(data.slice(1));
}
```

And here is the example of what the output should look like:

```
const headers = ['a', 'b', 'c'];//Should not be hardcoded - subject to change depending on the grader
const rows = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]];//Should not be hardcoded - subject to change depending on the grader
const result = rowsToObjects({headers, rows}) 
console.log(result);
// [{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}, {a: 4, b: 5, c: 6}, {a: 7, b: 8, c: 9}];
```

I would have known how to create a dictionary for each row if I could use a for loop, but we are not allowed to use while loops, for loops, for ... in loops, for ... of loops, forEach method, so I am struggling with coming up with a way to do this, and make my output look like the ones that is shown in the example.

Any help is welcome, and thank you very much!

Comment: For every row, create a new dictionary and fill it with properties. Where exactly do you have trouble?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. If what I have so far is correct, then I think I am ok with splitting the array into "header" and "rows". But I am not sure how to make it into a dictionary so I am struggling with that.

Comment: Seems a bit more advanced task than entry level beginner

Comment: Nice question. If this is an intro course they're doing better than the ones around my area. First thing is that you're passing an object to your function when you write ` { headers, rows } `, not an array. So you're likely having a problem solving this because you're attempting to use array methods on an object, which will error.

Comment: @charlietfl plus I find this JavaScript syntax very not intuitive

Comment: @zfrisch wait, array is an object.

Comment: @NathanBell well. the easiest way to understand is that brackets denote arrays [1,2,3] - braces denote objects {a: 1}. And yes, everything in JavaScript is an object,  but Arrays are a specific type of object. A regular object can't use Array methods like splice, push, or shift. I'd say the differentiation is important, but likely you'll confuse yourself if you think too hard on it when starting out. Basically { headers, rows } is an object, whereas [ headers, rows ] is an Array.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Array.prototype.reduce` on the `rows` array to iterate over each array in the `rows` 2-D array.

Then for each array in the 2-D array create a temporary object by using  `Array.prototype.reduce` to map the values from `headers` corresponding to each array value of the `rows` array using the index `i`:

```js
const headers = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
const rows = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]];
const result = rowsToObjects(headers, rows) 
console.log(result);
// [{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}, {a: 4, b: 5, c: 6}, {a: 7, b: 8, c: 9}];

function rowsToObjects(headers, rows){
  return rows.reduce((acc, e, idx) =>  {
     acc.push(headers.reduce((r, h, i)=> {r[h] = e[i]; return r; }, {}))
     return acc;
  }, []);
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Fullstack guy but we are not allowed to use foreach, for, while, for...in, for...of loops :( Is there any other way I can solve this problem?

Comment: @NathanBell I have used only `reduce` to get the expected output, but `reduce` internally will use loops to go over each element. So unless you have static data and want to hard code indexes there is no other option.

Comment: Could you please explain to me what the 3 arguments for reduce mean? I tried to look it up, but I can only find .reduce with 2 arguments.

Comment: @Nathan Bell the three arguments are: 1. the accumulator, which is the object you are reducing to. 2. The element from the array when you iterate 3. The index of the element in the array

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Array.reduce` to loop throgh all arrays  and reduce them to objects.

```js
function arrayToObjects(rows){
  const headers = rows.shift();//shift headers out of rows
  return rows.map(rowsToObjects);
  function rowsToObjects(row) {
    return  row.reduce((obj,e,i)=>{
      obj[headers[i]]=e;
      return obj;
    },{})
  }
}
console.log(arrayToObjects([['a', 'b', 'c'],[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]));
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, @TheMaster. We are not allow to hardcode "data" since it is subject to change. Is there a way to do this without hardcoding? Could you please tell me whether my way of creating headers and rows is correct? Also, is there a way to call `const result = rows.map(rowsToObjects);` inside the `rowsToObjects function`?

Comment: There's no advantage in using `reduce` over a simple loop, especially for a beginner.

Comment: @Bergi It seems He [isn't allowed to use loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58050534/javascript-make-a-key-value-data-structure-from-2-dimensional-arrayheader-row/58050645?noredirect=1#comment102499434_58050600)

Comment: Oh. Well then your answer is ok I guess :-) I'd recommend to reduce over the `headers` though, just in case the number of columns is different.

Comment: @Bergi Not sure what you mean by reduce over the headers, but, Highly doubt  varying number of headers will be the case. But, if so, then I'd also need to consider different number of columns for each row... , which would be unnecessary boilerplate for a beginner or for a solution.

Comment: @TheMaster I mean instead of doing  `row.reduce(…)`, rather go for `headers.reduce((obj, header, i) => { obj[header] = row[i]; return obj}, {})`. That guarantees that the objects always have the same properties, no matter how jagged the array is. (Also it avoids the nested bracket notation)

Comment: @Bergi Nice. But still doesn't guarantee perfection. say ``data = [['a','b','c'],[1,2,3],[3,4],[5,6,7,8]]``. Second row, last column `c` will be undefined and 8 will be missing. But you're right: It does guarantee that all the objects have the same properties.

Comment: @TheMaster Yes, having `undefined` for missing columns and omitting columns that we have no name for would be the expected result.

Comment: Could you please explain to me what the 3 arguments for reduce mean? I tried to look it up, but I can only find .reduce with 2 arguments. Also says `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

Comment: @Nathan `obj,e,i`: obj= object, the accumulator; e= the current `e`lement (in the row); i= ``i``ndex of current element. Read and practice [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Answer (score 1):

Looping through rows using `map` and then using `reduce` to associate each cell (`c`) from a row (`r`) to a header using the index (`i`).

Here is a one-liner to be fancy:

```js
function rowsToObjects(rows, headers) {
  return rows.map(r => r.reduce((o, c, i) => Object.assign(o, { [headers[i]]: c }), {}))
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain to me what the 3 arguments for reduce mean? I tried to look it up, but I can only find .reduce with 2 arguments. Also says `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

Comment: The first parameter (`o`) is the object we are building.
The second parameter (`c`) is the cell or value (1 to 9).
The third parameter (`i`) is the index. The function `rowsToObjects` takes as first parameter the array of `rows` and second parameter the array of `headers`.

Comment: what is i? Is it the index as a row number(ranging from r0 to r2), or as a column number (from c0 to c2)?

Comment: `i` is the index returned by the `reduce` function while it's looping through `rows`.